# array behaviour with auto and decltype

Tags: c++, arrays, auto, decltype

Can someone please explain me what's actually happening in the following code:-

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main(){
  int ia[]= {2,1,2,3,4,6,6,7,8,9};

  auto ia2(ia);
  *ia2= 19;
  for(auto i : ia){
    cout<<ia[i] << " " ;
  }

  //now my new ia = {5,1,2,3,4,6,6,7,8,9};
  decltype(ia) ia3= {0,1,2,3,4};

  for(auto i : ia3){
    cout<<ia[i] << endl ;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My output is coming as follows :-

```
21949 1 2 3 4 6 6 7 8 9 19
1
2
3
4
19
19
19
19
19
```

I am all confused, first of all I created an array ia with `2,1,2,3,4,6,6,7,8,9`
then I learned with **auto** you're actually creating pointer to the first element
then I changed the value at first element by using `*ia2= 19` which should have changed the value of **2** to **19** then I used for range loop to display the elements in **ia array** I used **decltype** as it doesn't create pointers but instead create an array. I again used for range loop to display elements but of **ia** instead of **ia3** and I don't understand how I am getting output like  this. Can somebody please let me understand this code.

Comment: `std::cout << i << std::endl` to print elements of array in for loop range-based.

Comment: `for(auto i : ia) { cout<<ia[i]; }` is wrong, it should simply be `for(auto i : ia){ cout<<i };`. you print `ia[ia[0]]` currently.*

Comment: After doing `decltype(ia) ia3= {0,1,2,3,4}; for(auto i : ia3){ cout<<i << endl ;}
` in second for range loop why Output for second for range loop is coming as :-
`0
1
2
3
4
0
0
0
0
0`
It should be like
`0
1
2
3
4`

Comment: `decltype(ia)` is `int[10]` - an array of 10 ints. So `ia3` is also an array of 10 ints. You provide initial values for 5 of them; the rest are initialized to zero. Then you print all 10 elements, zeros and all. If you wanted "an array of the same type as `ia` but with the number of elements determined by the initializer", that would be `decltype(ia[0]) ia3[] = {0,1,2,3,4};`

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik Nicely explained. Respect